# Adding to ObservableCollection and ListViewCollection grouping

Tags: wpf, collections, observablecollection

I have a ObservableCollection and I'm using a ListViewCollection to provide grouping by a particular property, in this case MyProperty.

The problem is when I add objects to ObservableCollection the grouping isn't updated in the ListView in the UI until I call the .Refresh() method on the ListCollectionView. I do see the data in the ListView control, but it isn't grouping.

I'm implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the Stuff object. Here is an example of the code.

```
ObservableCollection<Stuff> MyStuff = new ObservableCollection<Stuff>();
MyListView.ItemSource = MyStuff;

MyListCollectionView =    (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyListView.ItemsSource);
var groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("MyProperty");
MyListCollectionView .GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

Stuff newStuff = new Stuff();
newStuff.MyProperty = "Group A";
MyStuff.Add(newStuff); // Once added here, ListView shows item, but doesn't show correct grouping at this point
```

Anyone see what I may be doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: I need a few more details. 
1/Is your `MyListView` bound to `MyStuff` or to `MyListCollectionView` ? It should be the latter
2/ Is it all defined in code, or do you also have some Xaml? Xaml is also recommended for this kind of operation
An easy solution would be the xaml implementation. Do you have a requirement to write this in code?

Comment: Your code works, just add a few more Objects to the list to see that they are grouped properly. Ex: "Group A", "Group B", "Group A" the result is "Group A", "Group A", "Group B"

Comment: You should bind `ItemsSource` with `MyListCollectionView` and not `MyStuff`.

Comment: Thanks folks. Your help got me through this issue. @Damascus I have been playing around with doing in XAML and in code and I prefer the XAML approach.